# How to return a column from XML using Oracle XMLTABLE

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltable

I have some `XML` stored in a table. I need to be able to take this `XML` and pull out certain values.

I've written some code to try and return the value of the `<ns1:Int32/>` tag, but as of yet I have not been able to return a result.

I've found several examples online that use the `XMLTABLE` function, but unfortunately a lot of these examples use simpler `XML` than I have.

**XML**

```
<Rule Priority="0" Description="Description 1" Active="True" ReevaluationBehavior="Always" Name="Name 1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/workflow">
    <Rule.Condition>
        <RuleExpressionCondition Name="{p3:Null}" xmlns:p3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
            <RuleExpressionCondition.Expression>
                <ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression Operator="BooleanAnd" xmlns:ns0="clr-namespace:System.CodeDom;Assembly=System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                    <ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right>
                        <ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression Operator="GreaterThanOrEqual">
                            <ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right>
                                <ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression>
                                    <ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression.Value>
                                        <ns1:Int32 xmlns:ns1="clr-namespace:System;Assembly=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">11</ns1:Int32>
                                    </ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression.Value>
                                </ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression>
                            </ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right>
                        </ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression>
                    </ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right>
                </ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression>
            </RuleExpressionCondition.Expression>
        </RuleExpressionCondition>
    </Rule.Condition>
</Rule>
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT Rules2.*
FROM RULES Rules1,
XMLTABLE
(
    XMLNAMESPACES
    (
        'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS "p3",
        'clr-namespace:System;Assembly=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' AS "ns0",
        'clr-namespace:System;Assembly=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' AS "ns1",
        DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/workflow'
    )
    ,
    '/Rule/RuleExpressionCondition/CodeBinaryOperatorExpression/CodePrimitiveExpression'
    PASSING XMLPARSE(CONTENT Rules1.RULE WELLFORMED)
    COLUMNS "Int" INT PATH 'ns1:Int32'
) 
Rules2
;
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the value "of a tag"? Do you mean the value 11?

Comment: Yes, in this example I would mean 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong url in namespace definition for ns0. And wrong path in xmltable.  You can use the short version. Or provide full path. 
`/Rule/Rule.Condition/RuleExpressionCondition/RuleExpressionCondition.Expression/ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression/ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right/ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression/ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right/ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression/ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression.Value`

```
SELECT Rules2.*
FROM xmls Rules1,
XMLTABLE
(
    XMLNAMESPACES
    (
        'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS "p3",
        'clr-namespace:System.CodeDom;Assembly=System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' AS "ns0",
        'clr-namespace:System;Assembly=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' AS "ns1",
        DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/workflow'
    )
    ,
    '//ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression.Value'
    PASSING XMLPARSE(CONTENT Rules1.RULE WELLFORMED)
    COLUMNS "Int" INT PATH 'ns1:Int32'
) 
Rules2
```

Comment: Using the short version (with '//' will result in inferior performance. '//' should be avoided unless you are searching a recursive structure

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your search expression is

`/Rule/RuleExpressionCondition/CodeBinaryOperatorExpression/CodePrimitiveExpression`.

The expression is missing multiple nodes, right?